# Filter neighbour's INBOUND vertices with path labels in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangodb-graph

I have the following graph:

[image]

I'd like to write an AQL query that returns all vertices which are neighbor's INBOUND vertices colored in RED from the start vertex colored in GREEN.

I tried the following AQL to retrieve red vertices from the green vertex.

```
WITH collection_A, collection_W
LET A_Neighbors = (FOR t IN collection_edges
                    FILTER t._to == 'collection_W/W'
                    RETURN t._from)
                    
let all_w = []
for item in A_Neighbors
    let sub_w = (for v1 in collection_edges
                        FILTER v1._to == item
                        return v1 )
    return APPEND(all_w, sub_w)
```

Is there any good solution other than this? Because I'm not sure this gives the correct values for start vertex `collection_W/W`.

My `collection_edges` contains following two kind of documents.

```json
{
 _from: collection_W/w,
 _to: collection_A/a,
 label: INBOUND
}
```

and

```json
{
 _from: collection_A/a,
 _to: collection_W/w,
 label: OUTBOUND
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the goal of the query. Based on the image you drew, what would the correct result be? This sentence needs to be a little clearer: `I'd like to write an AQL query that returns all vertices which are neighbor's INBOUND vertices colored in RED from the start vertex colored in GREEN.`

Comment: I want to get all the red vertices starts from the green vertex as in the image.

Comment: Sounds like you want to traverse with a depth of 1 in ANY direction ("A" vertices), followed by another traversal in INBOUND direction ("W" vertex on the left-hand side)?

Comment: Actually, I want to get neighbors' neighbors from start vertex green.

Answer (score 0):

Given the diagram, I would suggest using a graph traversal specific `[min[..max]]` value, like this (using an [anonymous graph](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/aql/graphs-traversals.html#working-with-collection-sets)):

```js
WITH collection_A, collection_W
FOR vertex IN 2 ANY 'collection_W/W' // green start node
    collection_edges
    RETURN vertex
```

The `[min[..max]]` value can be a range (`1..3`) or it can be a single value (`1`).

- `0` will return the start node
- `1` will return adjacent nodes
- `2` will skip the adjacent nodes and return only nodes at the next level (if any)
- `2..999` will return all nodes (up to 999 hops away) from the start node

Further, if you want to make sure that you're only returning nodes from a specific collection, add a [filter](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/aql/functions-document.html#is_same_collection) for that:

```js
WITH collection_A, collection_W
FOR vertex IN 2 ANY 'collection_W/W' // green start node
    collection_edges
    FILTER IS_SAME_COLLECTION('collection_W', vertex)
    RETURN vertex
```

You can also filter on edges (if you've added a specific attribute/value to your edges):

```js
WITH collection_A, collection_W
FOR vertex, edge IN 2 ANY 'collection_W/W' // green start node
    collection_edges
    FILTER edge.someProperty == 'someValue' // only return vertices that are beyond matching edges
    RETURN vertex
```

Or limit the traversal with [PRUNE](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/aql/graphs-traversals.html#pruning):

```js
WITH collection_A, collection_W
FOR vertex, edge IN 2 ANY 'collection_W/W' // green start node
    collection_edges
    PRUNE edge.someProperty == 'someValue' // stop traversal when this is matched
    RETURN vertex
```